# How Do We Get SpannedString Objects From String Resources Using Data Binding?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-databinding

Florina Muntenescu wrote up [a cool post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f) about using `<annotation>` in string resources for being able to have flexible markup that you can process in your app using custom spans. I am trying to leverage it in data binding, but I cannot quite figure out how to get a `SpannedString` edition of the string resource from data binding.

In my layout, I have `app:thingy="@{@string/my_annotated_string}"` as an attribute on a `TextView`. I have a binding adapter set up to handle `thingy` attributes. However, the data binding system seems to insist that my value is a `String`.

I have tried:

```
@BindingAdapter("thingy")
@JvmStatic
fun handleThingy(textView: TextView, thingy: SpannedString) { /* stuff goes here */ }
```

and:

```
@BindingAdapter("thingy")
@JvmStatic
fun handleThingy(textView: TextView, thingy: Spanned) { /* stuff goes here */ }
```

and:

```
@BindingAdapter("thingy")
@JvmStatic
fun handleThingy(textView: TextView, @StringRes thingy: Int) { /* stuff goes here */ }
```

In all cases, I get `Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:thingy' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.TextView` build errors.

If I use `String` or `CharSequence` for the `thingy` parameter type, it builds, but then I get passed a `String` and I do not have my annotation spans from the string resource.

So, how can I either:

- Get the `SpannedString` corresponding to my string resource (i.e., what you get from `getText()` instead of `getString()`), or
- Get the string resource ID of my string resource, so I can call `getText()` myself to get my `SpannedString`

Comment: What is the `attr` type for `thingy`?

Comment: @BenP.: There is no `attr` for `thingy`. When the data binding compiler encounters a data binding expression, it looks for binding adapters based on the attribute name.

Comment: Hm, ok. I'm not too familiar with data binding... so how does the system "know" the type to expect? Do you have a `String getThingy()` method?

Comment: Well, I thought it used reflection to examine the method/function signature of the binding adapter implementation. It seems to do that in other places. In the above code snippets, the first parameter is the type of the widget you are using the binding expression on (`TextView`) and the second parameter is the type of the attribute value from the binding expression (`Int`, `String`, etc.). Perhaps it is just not that flexible when it comes to string resources. That's kinda the point of this question.

Comment: My question is how it knows it wants `String` as opposed to `float`, not `String` as opposed to `Spannable`

Comment: Oh, is it just because you're passing a string resource in the layout?

Comment: i'm afraid the only thing you could do is to pass a `"my_annotated_string"` string to your `handleThingy` adapter and use infamous `Resources#getIdentifier()` method

Comment: @pskink: From another SO post, I think I could have an `<import>` for my `R` class in the layout, and have a binding expression that calls `context.getText(R.string.my_annotated_text)` and use that. Either that or your proposal can serve as fallbacks, but they both are kinda icky. This feels like it should be more straightforward than that. Thanks for that suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

As an expression, `@string/my_annotated_string` evaluates to a string. Eventhough it resembles a string resource reference in XML, it's actually only a `String` value.

It would be nice to have a `@text/my_annotated_string` version as well, but as of the documentation this is not available.

Instead you'd have to use the actual resource within your binding expression:

```
app:thingy="@{string.my_annotated_string}"
app:thingy="@{context.getText(string.my_annotated_string)}"
```

This is assuming the import of the `string` class:

```
<import type="path.to.R.string"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a maybe slightly less icky way:

Define the annotated string.

```
<string name="my_annotated_string">A <annotation font="title_emphasis">cool</annotation> annotation <annotation font="title_emphasis">thingy</annotation>.</string>
```

Place a reference to that string resource into a `TypedArray`:

```
<resources>
    <array name="annotated_text">
        <item>@string/my_annotated_string</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Reference the `TypedArray` in the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:thingy="@{@typedArray/annotated_text}" />
```

Finally, set a `BindingAdapter` to capture the `SpannedString` with the annotations:

```
@BindingAdapter("thingy")
public static void setThingy(TextView textView, TypedArray strings) {
    SpannedString ss = (SpannedString) strings.getText(0);
    Object spans[] = ss.getSpans(0, ss.length(), Object.class);
}
```

Although a little involved, this works. If there are multiple strings, the array can be expanded.

Comment: That's an interesting approach -- thanks! IMHO, it is more complicated than what I had suggested in the question comments, which is more or less what tynn has in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145538/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe, but it is just an introduction of a `TypedArray` which is in the data binding universe as is the entire solution - nothing odd. Multiple strings, if needed, can be collected in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("thingy")
fun handleThingy(textView: TextView, @StringRes thingy: Int) { /* stuff goes here */ }
```

and instead of using `app:thingy="@{@string/my_annotated_string}"` pass resource into binding: `thingy="@string/my_annotated_string"` (without `app:`).

Comment: Thanks! However, this does not work. The binding adapter does not get invoked. AFAIK, data binding only works on attributes with binding expressions. Tested on AS 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

one can define just any data-type with `<import>`:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List<String>"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray<String>"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map<String, String>"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>
```

and then obtain the text from it:

```
android:text="@{sparse[index]}"
```

to define a `thingy` with data-type `SpannedString` (or one that `extends SpannedString`):

```
<data>
    <import type="com.acme.model.BindableSpannedString"/>
    <variable name="thingy" type="BindableSpannedString"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
</data>
```

the getter annotated with `@Bindable` should be index access:

```
android:text="@{thingy.getSpanAt(index)}"
```

[SpannedString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannedString) lacks the getter required to bind it, nor can one add annotations to framework classes.

Comment: "the name of the method matters" -- no, it does not. For example, in the documentation that you linked to, it shows a `loadImage()` function as a `@BindingAdapter`. Thanks, though!

Comment: @CommonsWare that example uses `app:` namespace (the default demands `@Bindable` getters and setters, which notify). the `@BindingConversion` annotation might probably be suitable for the use case, hence there is some kind of conversion required.

Comment: "that example uses app: namespace" -- that is my use case as well. For example, `thingy` is not a standard Android attribute. Your point about `@BindingConversion` is interesting -- I might be able to set one up that maps a string resource `Int` to a `SpannedString` and address the problem that way. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare extended on my answer, because generally it's a custom data-type. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannedString does not really have any getter for a span at an index. adding some class `BindableSpannedString extends SpannedString` in order add `@Bindable` getters should make the data-binding work - and nested values accessible.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for nested values. I am looking for a binding adapter to be handed the spanned value (as a `Spannable`, `SpannedString`, whatever) for processing in the binding adapter.

Comment: @CommonsWare it still would need a getter which returns a `String` value, that `app` and `thingy` namespaces are probably not even required, while binding `android:text` ...`Spanned implements CharSequence` which would provide method `getSpans(int start, int end, Class<T> type)`.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it is because I am a bit short on sleep, but I did not understand any of that.